# Dual-Wielding Spear Dancing Style

Tags: pathfinder-1e, two-weapon-fighting

The Spear Dancing Style chain of feats (Specifically [Spear Dancing Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/spear-dancing-style-combat-style/) itself), allows the use of any spear or polearm as a double weapon.

If you chose a one-handed weapon, such as the Trident, Short Spear or Sibat, could you then wield one spear in each hand and use Spear Dancing Style with both? (effectively quad-wielding)

Obviously something like the Fighter Advanced Weapon Training [Effortless Dual-Wielding](http://www.archivesofnethysbeta.com/AdvWeaponTrainingDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Effortless%20Dual-Wielding) or similar would be warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

The Double special weapon quality allows you to fight **as if fighting with two weapons** (a one-handed weapon and a light weapon).  Since you can't use two weapons in one hand, you can't use a double weapon as a double weapon with one hand.

Your scenario is essentially the same as dual-wielding small quarterstaffs (with a size penalty, of course). You're still limited to one attack each with your main- and off-hand weapons.

Using a double weapon in each hand lets you make one attack with each; using a double weapon with Spear Dancer Style lets you make two attacks with one weapon.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

The double special weapon features reads:

> Double: You can use a double weapon to fight **as if fighting with two weapons**, but if you do, you incur all the normal attack penalties associated with fighting with two weapons, just as if you were using a one-handed weapon and a light weapon.

Two weapon fighting reads:

> If you wield a second weapon in your off hand, you can get **one extra attack per round** with that weapon.

So if you are wielding 2 one-handed double weapons, you still only get one extra attack in your full-attack.

A point of ambiguity can be **with which** weapon you get that extra attack, since I can see arguments made for the second end of the main-spear as well as the primary end of the off-hand spear, but that does not change the fact that you would only get a single extra attack.

Personally I would let you choose which weapon you wanted the extra attack to be with.

Comment: Presumably a creature *can* use such a 1-handed double weapon *as a double weapon* in one hand, though, right? And just carry a shield or whatever in the other?

Comment: I honestly don't know, it could go either way. The only RAW double weapons are 2-handed, so I don't think it was a situation considered in the design.